# ReactJS fetch data from backend, show in a form, and send data back

Tags: reactjs

In my ReactJS frontend I am building a form where the user can view and edit settings. The form is part of a function that does the following:

- Call the backend to get the settigs. Store the result from backend in variable `data`
- Map/show the `data` in text fields
- When the user clicks "Submit" then send changes as json back to the backend.

**This is a picture of the flow:**

[image]

**This is a picture of the ReactApp:**

[image]

**This is my code so far:**

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function Settings() {
  
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);


    // Send general settings
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let result = await fetch("https://localhost:5002/api/update_settings", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: data,
      });
      let resultJson = await result.json();
      let resultMessage = resultJson['message']
      let resulData = resultJson['data']
      let resultError = resultJson['error']
      if (result.status === 200 || result.status === 201) {
        document.getElementById("feedback_div").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("feedback_p").innerHTML = resultMessage;
      }
      else{
        document.getElementById("feedback_div").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("feedback_p").innerHTML = resultError + " " + resultMessage;
      }
    };


    useEffect(() => {
      fetch('https://localhost:5002/api/get_settings')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => setData(json))

    }, []);
    

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Settings</h1>
      
        
        {/* Feedback */}
        <div id="feedback_div" style={{display: "none"}}><p id='feedback_p'>Feedback box is here</p></div>

        {/* Form */}
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>
            <p>Title</p>
            <input type="text" name="inp_title" value={data?.settings_website_title} onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.value)} />
            </label>

            <label>
            <p>Title short</p>
            <input type="text" name="inp_title_short" value={data?.settings_website_title_short} onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.value)}  />
            </label>

            <p><button>Submit</button></p>
        </form>
      
    </div>
    );
}
  
export default Settings;
```

**Backend get_settings return value:**

```
 {
   "settings_website_title", "My Website",
   "settings_website_title_short", "MyWeb"
 }
```

**My problems:**

How can I send the data back to the backend? I belive that when the user makes changes into the text box I call `onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.value)}` but I do not think this is correct?  Because `data` should be the JSON, and not a single value.

Also I get this error on this code:

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be
> controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined
> to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a
> controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the
> component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I do not think this is correct? Because data should be the JSON, and not a single value.

Indeed.  Instead of setting the entirety of state to one value, set it to an updated version of itself in which that one value is changed.  For example:

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="inp_title"
  value={data?.settings_website_title}
  onChange={(e) => setData({ ...data, settings_website_title: e.target.value })}
/>
```

You can extract multiple settings into a single update handler if you align the `name` of the element with the property being updated.  For example:

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="settings_website_title"
  value={data?.settings_website_title}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
and...
<input
  type="text"
  name="settings_website_title_short"
  value={data?.settings_website_title_short}
  onChange={handleChange}
 />
```

Then your `handleChange` function can be something like:

```
const handleChange = e => {
  setData({
    ...data,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
};
```

In either case, you're replacing the state object with a copy of itself, changing only the one property updated by that `<input>` value.

---

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled...

This is because the initial values for your inputs are `undefined` (or possibly `null`).  An empty string would be preferable in this case.  Instead of using optional chaining for the values, initialize state to a default.  For example:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
  settings_website_title: '',
  settings_website_title_short: ''
});
```

Then you don't need the optional chaining in the `value` properties on your `<input>` elements:

```
value={data.settings_website_title}
```

Since `data` will always be a valid object with the properties you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are in right direction but doing small mistakes. Please follow below instructions to save the data successfully.

```
  // 1. initialize your form inputs here,, it will be used to send data in api request body
const [data, setData] = useState({
    settings_website_title: "",
   settings_website_title_short: ""
 });

 // 2.  You can't override the data in @data varaible. So your input will look something like this.
 <input type="text" name="inp_title" value={data?.settings_website_title} onChange={(e) => setData({...data,  settings_website_title: e.target.value})} />


 // 3. on click of submit button call the method where you make api call
 <button onClick={(e) => {handleSubmit()}}>Submit</button>
```